# Fixed igx column

Tags: angular-ui, infragistics, igx-grid

Hi I have a igx grid in which one of the columns is filled out with delete-buttons.

I want to make this column fixed as shown here:

[image]

Can I exclude the column with the delete-buttons from pinning/hiding and all other operations and show it always on the first position in the igx-grid. I do not want the user to be able to perform any operations on the column with delete-buttons. The user should be able to pin/hide/move etc. the other columns.

Currently the delete column is shown as pinned, which I do not want, because the column is shown without name:

[image]

Here is my grid:

```
<igx-grid igxPreventDocumentScroll
          #grid1
          [height]="'500px'" width="80%" [autoGenerate]='false'
          rowHeight ="60px"
          [batchEditing]="true"
          [data]="posts"
          style="margin-top: 1%; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; "
          [showToolbar]="true"
          [allowFiltering]="true"
          [columnHiding]="true"
          [hiddenColumnsText]="'hidden'"
          [columnPinning]="true"
          [pinnedColumnsText]="'pinned'"
          [primaryKey]="'lot'"
          (cellEditDone)="cellEditDoneHandler($event)"
          >

  <igx-column width="170px" field="monat" dataType="string" header="Monat" [resizable]="true" [sortable]="true" [editable]="true" [movable]="true" [cellClasses]="condFormatting">
    <ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
      <div class="cellvalue">{{cell.value}}</div>
        <button igxButton="icon" (click)="editSelectedData(cell.id.rowID,cell.column.field, cell.value)">
          <igx-icon fontSet="material" style="color: black; ">edit</igx-icon>
        </button>
    </ng-template>
  </igx-column>

  <igx-column width="170px" field="datum" dataType="string" header="Datum" [resizable]="true" [sortable]="true" [editable]="true" [movable]="true" [cellClasses]="condFormatting">
    <ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
      <div class="cellvalue">{{cell.value}}</div>
      <button igxButton="icon" (click)="editSelectedData(cell.id.rowID,cell.column.field, cell.value)">
        <igx-icon>edit</igx-icon>
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </igx-column>

  <igx-column width="100px" [filterable]="false" [pinned]="true" style="position: fixed;">
    <ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
      <button igxButton="icon" [disabled]="cell.row.deleted" (click)="deleteRow(cell.id.rowID)">
        <igx-icon>delete</igx-icon>
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </igx-column>

</igx-grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to take a different approach - the igx-grid has a built-in way to handle such functionality by taking levarage of the ActionStrip component, [topic with sample and description.](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/action-strip#usage-in-grids)
[image]

Upon row hover action, an overlay area will apear where you can define as many custom actions you want, in the case of the demo, it will add only a Delete icon for row deletion.

As for the initial approach that you described, it can be achieved with a lot of custom logic which could lead to maintanance problems in the future. Although, you can go ahead and create a Custom Toolbar Hiding Action by providing a custom UI - [this topic provide explanation on how to set custom content.](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/toolbar#custom-content). Basically, you can add a [button and overlay](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/overlay-position#usage) and within this overlay provide a list of all columns, expect the "Delete column", and upon column selection perform column hiding wit the grid API.